# Using image or xaml for buttons

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I was wondering the need for custom xaml code for buttons.
Using images like in html should be faster.
Yours thoughts please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of WPF is that it is independent of pixel resolution or DPI.  If you use raster images for the buttons it is no longer DPI independent and can look bad on some resolutions.  If, instead, you use WPF objects and geometries, those will look almost exactly the same on any DPI.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you want to change something small to do with the button? Using custom XAML allows me to apply the same template to all my buttons, and change them all by just changing that template. It also means that I can tweak small things without the need to constantly regenerate those images.

As for speed, you're best off not pre-empting the framework's optimisations until you actually encounter a performance issue.

EDIT: I should also note that the [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) doesn't inherit from `Button`, and as such you can't do the direct binding to an `ICommand` property in the ViewModel.

Comment: I am talking about using an Image in the content of button just for display. This too can use template.

Comment: If you want to do it, then benchmark it. Create two windows, each with a few hundred buttons, and see which is created faster.

Regardless I doubt there'll be an improvement, and if there is it's a lot of effort to achieve it.